# Manhwa where the main character starts as a healer then starts using a dagger

Tags: story-identification, manga

It starts with the main character as a healer and no one wants him in the party, because he is weak. Then he joins a party in a dungeon and, after clearing the dungeon, they wanted to fight a boss. The boss killed everyone except him, then he killed it with a dagger. After that, he joined a tutorial and changed it and it showed a boss again, and he started fighting it and got stronger.

Comment: Is there something special about the dagger? Does he turn out to have a "Dagger Master" skill? Is he aware that he's in a game? Is the world turned into a game? Are other people aware of the interface? What sort of monster was the boss? When you say "changes it", do you mean the dagger, the tutorial, the dungeon, the boss?

Comment: About what time did you read this story? (A few months ago? A few years ago?) What did the main character look like? What did the boss look like? Are there any other pieces of information you can give us?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely *[The Blade of Evolution: Walking Alone in the Dungeon](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-blade-of-evolution-walking-alone-in-the-dungeon)*. It is licensed by [Bilibili](https://www.bilibilicomics.com/detail/mc8?utm_source=mgd).

> Although Lu Xin awakens his **healer talent, his healing abilities are abysmal**. During a dungeon run, **Lu Xin's entire team gets wiped out**, leaving him as the only survivor. He activates the hidden condition "The Last High Priest" and obtains a "two-handed sword". At the same time, he activates the "two-handed sword's" development system...

The main character is a weak healer. No one wants him in their party as a result, but two friends invite him to a dungeon. They run into a hidden boss that kills everyone else, but Lu Xin manages to kill it at the end. Unlike in the question, he kills it with his friend's sword, not a dagger. This boss drops another sword.

After this, he enters the "novice dungeon" and it changes due to the sword he received earlier, becoming significantly more dangerous. Within it, he fights a large number of elementals, and another boss.